# Trouble Loading Expo React Native On Expo Go

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, native-base

Im having trouble rendering my Expo React Native App app in Expo Go. App is completely fine on web but when I try to render on mobile I get these errors. Before when I removed certain elements it was working but now that I've added a lot more libraries such as native base Im started to see more errors appear. Im somewhat new to coding so bear with me. Thank You!

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Mobile Response
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Original Code
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add alt prop  to Image component
   like this `<Image source={} height={} width={} alt="description of image" />`
2. border is not valid style property use from this
   "borderBottomColor",
   "borderBottomLeftRadius",
   "borderBottomRightRadius",
   "borderBottomWidth",
   "borderColor",
   "borderLeftColor",
   "borderLeftWidth",
   "borderRadius",
   "borderRightColor",
   "borderRightWidth",
   "borderStyle",
   "borderTopColor",
   "borderTopLeftRadius",
   "borderTopRightRadius",
   "borderTopWidth",
   "borderWidth`
3. for alignItems you need to pass any one of these "flex-start", "flex-end", "center", "baseline" or "stretch"